# Reuse webpack vendor bundle?

Tags: webpack

Our app puts all third-party dependencies (jquery, react, etc) in a vendor bundle. The app itself is sometimes embedded inside another requirejs app sharing the same dependencies. So we'd like to share the bundle.

As per the docs, we tried setting `libraryTarget` to both `var` and `amd`. We've also tried naming the library using `library`. However, when we `requirejs` the bundle in another app, the resulting object doesn't have the vendor libraries. Am I misunderstanding how the library packaging works?

```
/* requirejs app */
require(['vendor.bundle.js'], function(vendor) {
  console.log(vendor)
  console.log(libraryName)
}
```

Actual output (none of these are vendor libraries except Converter)

```
 Converter: (e)
 extension: (e,t)
 extensions: Object
 getAllExtensions: ()
 getDefaultOptions: (e)
 getOption: (e)
 getOptions: ()
 helper: Object
 removeExtension: (e)
 resetExtensions: ()
 resetOptions: ()
 setFlavor: (e)
 setOption: (e,t)
 subParser: (e,t)
 validateExtension: (e)
```

Desired output: an object containing all the 3rd-party libraries:

```
{
   React: //...,
   Baconjs: //.....
}
```